# Inheritance from abstract in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract

I have a class:

```
public abstract BaseClass
{
    public RequestType MethodOne(Request request)
    {
        // some work here with objectOne
        return PostMethodOne(objectOne);
    }
    public abstract RequestType PostMethodOne(Request request);
}
```

Then i ihnerit from base class:

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    public override PostMethodOne(Request request)
    {
     // some work with request
        return request;
    }
}
```

Is methodOne called and then i can work with request on the PostMethod after it is gone through methodOne?
do i have to call base.MethodOne ?

Comment: Can you please make your question a bit more clear, I do not understand it.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: It's called a Template Method pattern and it's completely fine. What your question is about?

Comment: If your object is a `ChildClass` and you call `MethodOne()` via a `BaseClass` reference the overridden `PostMethodOne()` will be executed. This is working because of polymorphism.

Comment: Add `printlines`

Comment: is your question: "Can I just call `MethodOne` and the appropriate `PostMethodOne` of the `ChildClass` will be called automatically?" ??

Comment: `public override PostMethodOne(Request request)` I am sure, it is a typo, but the return type is missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`MethodOne` is not abstract or virtual, which means it is simply inherited by `ChildClass`.

`POstMethodOne` is abstract, and as such you must implement it in `ChildClass`. A caller doing this:

```
var myInstance = new ChildClass();
myInstance.MethodOne();
```

Will call `MethodOne` from `BaseClass` which in turn calls `PostMethodOne` - this is abstract and implemented in `ChildClass` - which will be called automatically.

[This is a pretty common pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern), and youve made just one possible mistake - `POstMethodOne` should probably be `protected` not `public`.

Comment: The caller is a factory that matches Product with appropriate child class.

So if the factory points at the child class, will the request be enchant from MethodOne  ?

Comment: @dioannou I dont understand the question. What does "enchant" mean??

Comment: i retyped the question sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @dioannou er... where did you retype it?

Comment: Sorry: My question was: the returned PostMethodOne will carry the enchanted request object without me having to call base.MethodOne() is that correct ?

Comment: @dioannou I dont think enchant/enchanted is the word you're looking for.

Comment: @Jamiec :D it's like scrabble here :D

Comment: @Jamiec i meant enhanced, my bad. urf.. sorry for this, anxiety levels hitting new hights. To the code i posted in the begining, do i have to call base.MethodOne() or will MethodOne be executed anyway without me calling it on some way or the other. Will the request object in the inherited anbstract method be empty or will have values set in the MethodOne() ? I don know if i am making any sense.

Comment: @dioannou Im afraid you're not making much sense (to me, at least). My best advice is to try it.. step through it with a debugger to understand what gets called when. The request object will be set to whatever you set it to! Its just like any other method - there is no magic.